# Unable to filter on field on edit.php page

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, filters, admin

I'm borrowing from the code at [Add filter menu to admin list of posts (of custom type) to filter posts by custom field values](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45436/add-filter-menu-to-admin-list-of-posts-of-custom-type-to-filter-posts-by-custo) to add a filter to my custom post type with the `parse_query` filter:

```
function grievance_posts_filter( $query ){
    global $pagenow;
    $type = 'post';
    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        $type = $_GET['post_type'];
    }
    if ( 'grievance' == $type && is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && isset($_GET['step']) && $_GET['step'] != '') {
        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'my_first_plugin_fields[step]';
        $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = 2;
    }
}
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'grievance_posts_filter' );
```

In the above code, I have hard-coded the value of the the `meta_value` to troubleshoot. I expect the above code to show me only the posts with the `step` value is set to "2". However, instead of filtering the posts, the edit.php page is not showing any posts at all. I don't think I'm using the right values for the `meta_key` and `meta_value` elements. I'm not sure what to put there. My meta_key has multiple sub-keys associated with it.

I have also tried:

```
        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'my_first_plugin_fields';
        $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = array( 'step' => 2 );
```

but this did not work either.

I also attempted:

```
    $meta = [ 'my_first_plugin_fields' => [ 'key' => 'step', 'value' => '2', 'compare' => '=' ] ] ;
    $query->query_vars['meta_query'] = $meta;
```

without success.

Answer (score 0):

Won't let me comment and possibly a silly question but have you tried putting die(); just after the if statement to be sure the conditional is working correctly?

Other wise I force meta values to become terms in an hidden taxonomy and utilize those as filters.  I can expand on that if you like but don't want to go that way too much as that isn't the topic of the question.

Comment: Yes, the code in the statement is definitely getting executed. I verified by removing the "if" statement.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this with:

```
        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'my_first_plugin_fields';
        $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = sprintf(':"step";s:1:"%s";', $_GET['step']);
        $query->query_vars['meta_compare'] = 'LIKE';
```

Which seems like an awful hack. If there is a better way, I'd love to hear.